# Firestore, does each field retrieve count as a read or only document itself

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If I have a document with, let's say, 10-15 fields. If I want to retrieve all of those fields, do they count as 10-15 reads? Or will I just be charged with 1 read because it's only one document that contains them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are charged 1 read **per document read**

More details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations

Comment: So if I understand it correctly after reading your answer + the link, I could retrieve 10 fields from a single document and it would only count as one read, since I'm charged 1 read per document read. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: You are charged one document read for each document that is read on/from the server, no matter how many fields are in that document. There is no per-field charge, although of course a document with more fields will typically use more bandwidth (which is also charged).